# Is there a way to save benchmark results as JSON?

Tags: rust, benchmarking

This [commit (issue #19145)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19145), removed the `--save-metrics` option when running benchmarks. Is there a way to will generate JSON of the benchmark runs in a formal that is similar to `--save-metrics`?

Comment: Note: SO does not deal in software recommendations, so asking for a crate is off-topic according to the guidelines. An open-ended question (such as your title) is however fine, so I suggest removing the mention to "another crate".

Comment: @MatthieuM. I was wondering if the functionality was moved to an external crate, but you make a valid point.

Comment: @Shepmaster? Wait, so `rustc` doesn't run benchmarks?! I'm asking, because if Cargo runs benchmarks I might be able to change stuff there or duplicate the way benchmarks are handled.

Comment: @DanielFath it's a pedantic distinction. `rustc` is the Rust compiler, taking your source code and producing a binary. The compiler produces a binary that, when run, produces benchmarks. If you went with your terminology, then `rustc` would be responsible for *everything* that a compiled Rust program does :-)

Answer (score 0):

The default test harness `libtest` (this is what actually runs the tests) has a CLI parameter `--format`. It accepts the values `pretty` (default), `terse` and `json`.  However, the JSON output is still unstable (as of Rust 1.37) and thus requires a nightly compiler. To enable this unstable feature you additionally need the flag `-Z unstable-options`. Combining everything:

```
cargo bench -- --format=json -Z unstable-options
```

This outputs something like this:

```
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.02s
     Running target/release/deps/foo-177d129f966b1f75
{ "type": "suite", "event": "started", "test_count": 1 }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "bench_foo" }
{ "type": "bench", "name": "bench_foo", "median": 10138124, "deviation": 165468 }
{ "type": "suite", "event": "ok", "passed": 0, "failed": 0, "allowed_fail": 0, "ignored": 0, "measured": 1, "filtered_out": 0 }
```

This is probably not the same as the original `--save-metrics` flag, but it's at least something.

It's also worth point out that some external benchmarking frameworks like [Criterion](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs) will always save the raw data as JSON. So you might want to consider using this to do the statistical analysis yourself.